# MySQL select using wildcard (but wildcard in field)

Tags: mysql, select, wildcard

I have a mysql 5 table with a char field holding

```
DOG
DOUG
CAT
MOUSE
```

Now I want to SELECT on this field, finding any rows where that field exist within a string, like "DOGGY".  (This is opposite of how you normally use a wildcard).  So I want a select something like:
**SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE FIELD IS SUBSTRING OF "DOGGY"**

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you explain more what you're trying to do?

Comment: Specifically, do you want to find rows where the field has a substring of "doggy" (that is, the text contains some of the letters in "doggy" but not necessarily all of them)? Or do you want to find rows where "doggy" is a substring of the field (that is, the field contains the word "doggy" plus possibly other text)?

In the first case, your query would match rows with text like "dog", "dogg", and "gy". 

In the second case, your query would match rows with text like "hello doggy" and "what's that doggy doing there?"

Comment: I want to find rows where the fields contain a substring of the word I am searching on.  So in the example above, my select would return the row with "DOG" in the field.

Answer (score 18):

```
select * from mytable where 'doggy' like concat('%',mycol,'%')
```

Comment: \*mind blown\* -- I use LIKE all the time but it never occurred to me to reverse the parameters like this, and I had to try it myself before I was convinced it could work. I guess I'm just a noob, but I think this is a pretty awesome answer.

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to use [`LOCATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) to achieve this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE LOCATE(MyField, 'DOGGY') != 0;
```

Comment: Just played with this function and seems to work as required / upvote